# What does a "convention" mean in mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, terminology, convention

We all know that $0!=1$, the degree of the zero polynomial equals $-\infty$, the interval$[a,a)=(a,a]=(a,a)=\emptyset$ ... and so on, are conventions in mathematics. So is a convention something that we can't prove with mathematical logic, or is it just intuitions, or something 
that mathematicians agree about?
Are they the same as axioms? What does "convention" mean in mathematics?
And is $i^2 = -1$ a convention? If not how can we prove existence of such number?

Comment: $i^2=-1$ isn't a convention, you can prove it using the definition!

Comment: One reason behind $0!=1$ is that the formula ${n\choose{r}}=\frac{n!}{r!(n-r)!}$ holds even when $r=0$. I think conventions behind others also has the same kind of reason

Comment: $[a,a)=\lbrace x\in \mathbb{R} : a\leq x\mbox{ and } x<a\rbrace=\emptyset $, so this is not convention and similarly the others.

Comment: Same for $(a,a)=\{x \in \mathbb{R}:\ x<a \text{ and } x>a\}$.

Comment: The definition isn't supplied by mathematics. "Convention" is just an English word with no special mathematical meaning.

Comment: what does it mean in a mathematical point of view? i mean that mathematicians claim that something is a convention why?

Comment: It is a convention that the complex number which, when squared, gives $-1$, and whose imaginary part is positive, is called i, and not e.g. $\alpha$ or ŋ.

Comment: so why choosing is to be equal to $-1$ and not something else?

Comment: As it turns out, given any $\alpha\in\Bbb C\smallsetminus\Bbb R$, we can uniquely describe every $z\in\Bbb C$ as $z=x+y\alpha$ for some $x,y\in\Bbb R$ dependent only on $z$. We chose $i$ (which stands for "imaginary unit") in particular largely (perhaps only) because it makes complex arithmetic simpler.

Comment: Maybe this is an example.  It is a **convention** that $0$ belongs to the set $\mathbb N$ of natural numbers.  And it is another convention that $0$ does not belong to $\mathbb N$.

Comment: To my mind, a "convention" implies that a choice is being made between multiple options. It's a convention that mathematicians measure angles in radians instead of degrees; there are different implications for either choice.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

To answer the question in the title, I would say: 'convention' in mathematics means exactly the same as in ordinary English.

As for your examples: $0!:=1$ and $[a,a):=\emptyset$ are definitions. It is a *convention* not to use a different definition, or to leave it undefined. Of course in this sense, every definition is a convention.

It think that informally, one says a certain definition (such as the two above) is '(just) convention', to mean that they are 'extreme' or 'degenerate' cases, and leaving them undefined would still make the theory go through, but it is more convenient to define them anyway (for example to prevent having to exclude this extreme case in statement of theorems). For example, I think you could get by not defining $[a,a)$ or $[a,b]$ for $b<a$, but then in statements (and proofs) about general intervals $[a,b)$ you are forced to explicitly state and check whether $b>a$ which could be tiresome.

Answer (score 11):

A convention is a choice made because it is convenient--or at least, less inconvenient than the alternative(s).

For an example of a definition of convenience, let me answer your question regarding $i$ (from comments and original post) more explicitly. In particular, we may **define** the complex plane and complex arithmetic as follows: Let $\Bbb C:=\Bbb R^2$ with componentwise addition--that is, $$\langle a,b\rangle\oplus\langle c,d\rangle:=\langle a+c,b+d\rangle,$$ with "$+$" being real addition--and with multiplication defined as $$\langle a,b\rangle\odot\langle c,d\rangle:=\langle a\cdot c-b\cdot d,a\cdot d+b\cdot c\rangle,$$ with "$\cdot$" being real multiplication and "$-$" being real subtraction.

Now, we can show that these are well-defined operations, and it is readily verified that $\bigl\{\langle a,0\rangle:a\in\Bbb R\bigr\}$ under $\oplus$ and $\odot$ behaves exactly like $\Bbb R$ under $+$ and $\cdot$.  Treating $\Bbb C$ as a real vector space in two dimensions (which it is, as I alluded to in my comment above), the standard ordered basis for $\Bbb R^2$ is $\bigl\{\langle 1,0\rangle,\langle 0,1\rangle\bigr\}$. The former acts as $\odot$-multiplicative identity on all of $\Bbb C$, and we see also that $\langle 0,1\rangle\odot\langle 0,1\rangle=\langle -1,0\rangle$. Identifying those $\Bbb C$-pairs of form $\langle a,0\rangle$ with their real counterparts $a$, and **defining** $$i:=\langle 0,1\rangle,$$ we find that every complex number can be uniquely expressed in the form $x+iy$ (with $x,y\in\Bbb R$), and that $i^2=-1$. (The other properties of $\Bbb C$ can also be deduced, but that's another story.)

Note, we didn't *prove* that such a number as $i$ "exists"...we simply defined a structure and specified an element of that structure, which happens to have the properties that we ascribe to $i$. We could as easily have defined $$i:=\langle 0,-1\rangle,$$ without losing any of those properties, and really only chose the definition we did because it accords with the standard ordered basis for $\Bbb R^2$.

Answer (score 0):

$0^0=1$ instead of $0$ or the more correct* *indeterminate* could be termed a convention because it is just often much more useful to call that the result.

*I say "more correct" because you can define functions which, at a limit, $0^0$ has any value, though Wikipedia does limit the non-1 case somewhat, and mentions the range of views on its 'value' [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exponentiation#Zero_to_the_power_of_zero).

Comment: I strongly disagree that it would  be "more correct" to leave it undefined. If $Y^X$ is the set of functions from $X$ to $Y$, we have $\left|Y^X\right | = |Y|^{|X|}$ for every set $X$ and $Y$.  When $X$ and $Y$ are both empty, there is exactly one such function, so $0^0 = 1$. Leaving $0^0$ undefined would also spoil the binomial theorem and many other fundamental results.

Comment: "Indeterminate" and "undefined" are two rather different things, FWIW.