# magnitude of a root of complex expression plus complex expression

Tags: complex-numbers, arithmetic

If I had an expression $|a+bi+\sqrt(c+di)|^{2}$, how would I evaluate this? I know how to evaluate the magnitude of a complex expression or the root of a complex expression separately but not when they are combined.

Comment: Calculate $\sqrt{c+di}$ according to your definition of the square root for complex numbers (principal value, maybe?), then the problem reduces to the $u+iv$ case you know.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I was able to figure out the solution. Just for reference, I used this post as reference: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/664962/what-is-the-square-root-of-complex-number-i.

Comment: Glad it helped. That said, I hope you also noted the `unfortunately, this cannot be answered definitively` caveat in the accepted answer to the linked question, and the reference to the [principal value of the complex square root](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principal_value#Square_root) in my previous comment. Your question is not complete unless you spell out *what* the definition is for the $\sqrt{\,\cdot\,}$ complex square root being used.

Answer (score 0):

Well, when we have $\text{z}_1\space\wedge\space\text{z}_2\in\mathbb{C}$:

$$\text{D}:=\left|\text{z}_1+\sqrt{\text{z}_2}\right|\le\left|\text{z}_1\right|+\left|\sqrt{\text{z}_2}\right|=\left|\text{z}_1\right|+\sqrt{\left|\text{z}_2\right|}=$$
$$\sqrt{\Re^2\left(\text{z}_1\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}_1\right)}+\sqrt{\sqrt{\Re^2\left(\text{z}_2\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}_2\right)}}=$$
$$\sqrt{\Re^2\left(\text{z}_1\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}_1\right)}+\left(\Re^2\left(\text{z}_2\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}_2\right)\right)^\frac{1}{4}\tag1$$

And the square root of a complex number:

$$\sqrt{\text{z}_2}=\Re\left(\sqrt{\text{z}_2}\right)+\Im\left(\sqrt{\text{z}_2}\right)\cdot i\tag2$$

Where:

- $$\Re\left(\sqrt{\text{z}_2}\right)=\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\Re^2\left(\text{z}_2\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}_2\right)}+\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)}{2}}\tag3$$
- $$\Im\left(\sqrt{\text{z}_2}\right)=\pm\space\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\Re^2\left(\text{z}_2\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}_2\right)}-\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)}{2}}\tag4$$

So, when we want to find:

$$\text{D}=\sqrt{\Re^2\left(\text{z}_1+\sqrt{\text{z}_2}\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}_1+\sqrt{\text{z}_2}\right)}\tag5$$

Where:

- $$\Re\left(\text{z}_1+\sqrt{\text{z}_2}\right)=\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)+\Re\left(\sqrt{\text{z}_2}\right)=$$
  $$\Re\left(\text{z}_1\right)+\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\Re^2\left(\text{z}_2\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}_2\right)}+\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)}{2}}\tag6$$
- $$\Im\left(\text{z}_1+\sqrt{\text{z}_2}\right)=\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)+\Im\left(\sqrt{\text{z}_2}\right)=$$
  $$\Im\left(\text{z}_1\right)\pm\space\sqrt{\frac{\sqrt{\Re^2\left(\text{z}_2\right)+\Im^2\left(\text{z}_2\right)}-\Re\left(\text{z}_2\right)}{2}}\tag7$$