# What is the result of $2^{{2}^{{2}^{{2}^{0}}}}$?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, exponentiation

What is the result of $2^{{2}^{{2}^{{2}^{0}}}}$?

It seems simple but I don't understand it.

Edit: Whoever is down-voting, please leave a comment as to why...

Comment: Related: [What is the order when doing $x^{y^z}$ and why?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633790/what-is-the-order-when-doing-xyz-and-why).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is the order when doing $x^{y^z}$ and why?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633790/what-is-the-order-when-doing-xyz-and-why)

Answer (score 9):

$$2^0=1$$
$$2^{2^0}=2^1=2$$
$$2^{2^{2^0}}=2^2=4$$
$$2^{2^{2^{2^0}}}=2^4=16$$

Answer (score 5):

$2^{2^{2^{2^0}}}$ = 
$2^{2^{2^{1}}}$ = 
$2^{2^{2}}$ = 
$2^{4}$ = 
16

Answer (score -1):

$2^{2^{2^{2^0}}} =2^4 =16$. Just gave the answer.