# Difference between calculator and google calc for power

Tags: exponentiation, power-towers

I tried to compute the power of 2^2^2^2 on google calculator and my casio calculator but both are giving different results. same is true for 3^3^3.
Please explain me the difference between two expressions.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your calculator is interpreting it as this:

$${{2^2}^2}^2 = ((2^2)^2)^2 = (4^2)^2 = 16^2 = 256$$

Google is interpreting it as this:

$${{2^2}^2}^2 = 2^{(2^{(2^2)})} = 2^{(2^4)} = 2^{16} = 65536$$

Similarly with the threes.

Technically Google is correct because order of operations says to do exponents first.  So when we want to evaluate $2^{\color{red}{2}^{\color{blue}{2^2}}}$, order of operations says to evaluate the $\color{red}{{2^{\color{blue}{2^2}}}}$ first, i.e., evaluate the exponent first.  Apply this rule again and it tells us we're supposed to evaluate the $\color{blue}{2^2}$ first, which is $4.$  Therefore $\color{red}{{2^{\color{blue}{2^2}}}} = 2^4 = 16$, and so $2^{\color{red}{2}^{\color{blue}{2^2}}} = 2^{16} = 65536$.

Comment: What is correct mathematically?

Comment: @shivgarg, technically Google is correct because order of operations says to do exponents first.  Also see my edit in my answer.

Comment: "*what is correct mathematically?*" is also answered in greater detail in the linked question that you should see a link to above, but [here it is again](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633790/what-is-the-order-when-doing-xyz-and-why) in case you missed it.

Comment: In cases like this it never hurts to be explicit about the order you intend.  Use parens to instruct Google (or a more modern calculator) how you want it processed.

Comment: Actually, I don't think there is a "correct" answer.  It's a matter of convention, and the convention is not set in stone.

Comment: @RobertIsrael So if you instructed your students to evaluate $2^{2^2}$, would you mark them off if they did it one way or the other?  Oh, wait ... :)

Answer (score 2):

The difference lies in the applied order of operations.

The Casio calculator does operations strictly left to right unless you break it with parentheses:

> 2^2^2^2 = 4^2^2 = 16^2 = 256

But Google evaluates the entire expression (correctly) using right-to-left order or operations for the stacked powers:

> 2^2^2^2 = 2^2^4 = 2^16 = 65536

Comment: What is correct mathematically?

Comment: I stated that in my answer.