# Solve $i^{i^{i^\ldots}}$

Tags: complex-numbers, exponentiation, tetration, power-towers

How to find  $$i^{i^{i^\ldots}} \quad :\quad i=\sqrt{-1}$$
I'm able to find the solution for the finite powers 
using 
$$i=e^{i(2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})}\quad:\quad k\in\mathbb{Z}$$
$$i^{i}=e^{-(2k\pi+\frac{\pi}{2})}$$
$$i^{i^{i}}=e^{-i(2\pi k+\frac{\pi}{2})}=-i$$
$$i^{i^{i^i}}=e^{(2\pi k+\frac{\pi}{2}) }$$
$$\text{and so on}$$
but what should be the approach to solve for infitie powers$\space$?

Comment: Note that one should define exponentiation to be single-valued by choosing a branch, which would make this question clearer...

Comment: Your method of computing the iterates is not correct. Note that $(i^i)^i \ne i^{(i^i)}$.

Comment: @Shalop What should be the correct method of computing the iterates?

Comment: Going by your rules, we say $i^z = e^{\big(2k+\frac12\big)i\pi z}$. Let us call this function $f(z)$. Now compute $f(i)$. Then compute $f(f(i))$. Then compute $f(f(f(i)))$. You will see that it is not the same as what you are doing.

Comment: See also: [What is the order when doing $x^{y^z}$ and why?](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1633790).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$X = i^{i^{i^{\cdot}}}$

So $X = i^X$.

So $\log (X) = X \log (i)$.

So ${\log (X) \over X} = \log (i)$.

So $X = i W(-i)$, where $W$ is the Lambert $W$ or PolyLog function.

*Mathematica* evaluates this to $X = 0.44 + 0.36 i$.

Here's a graph on the imaginary plane of 200 successive exponentiations with the solution as a red dot:

[image]

Comment: This is a fixed point but proving that it converges is more work.

Comment: @parsiad.  Fair enough.  Good thing the OP didn't ask for a proof of convergence!

Comment: @DavidG.Stork Does series converge to any particular value?

Comment: This is purely formal, obviously.