# Show that ${n}^{n^{n}}>n(n!)((n!)!)$ where n is a positive integer greater than or equal to $3$.

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics

Show that ${n}^{n^{n}}>n(n!)((n!)!)$ where n is a positive integer greater than or equal to $3$.

My attempt:

Rewrite ${n}^{n^{n}} =n^{n} n^{n} … n^{n} n^{n} $ and $n(n!)((n!)!)=n(n)(n-1)(n-2)…1(n!)(n!-1)…1$.

Since $n^{n}\gt n!$, $n^{n} n^{n} … n^{n} n^{n}\gt n!n!…n!n!=n!^{n}$.

I tried to show that $n!^{n}\gt n(n)(n-1)(n-2)…1(n!)(n!-1)…1$, but I don’t know how.

Please give me a hint instead of a solution.

Comment: you typed in ${n^n}^{n}$  which is equal to $n^{n^2} $  I suspect  you ought to have  $n^{n^n}  =  n^{ \left(n^n  \right)} $  So:  what is the source of the problem?

Comment: Well we are a question-answer site, so this question will be receiving a full answer and not just a hint.

Comment: @Mike Yes, I meant I prefer hint not that I you should not give an answer lol.

Comment: Note that $(n/e)^n < n! < (n/e)^{n+1}$.

Comment: Please write this correctly. You are meaning $(n^n)^n=n^{n^2}$?

Comment: Anyway the top part of my answer is the hint, the bottom part answers more fully.

Comment: Since you typed {n^n}^{n}, I guess that what you mean is not n^{n^n} like in @Mike's answer. Please clarify your post by inserting parenthesis.

Comment: I saw $n^{n^n}$ but the Mathjax was formatting funny. Sometimes it came out $n^{nn}$.

Comment: Especially because $(n^n)^n = n^{n^2} << (n!)!.$

Comment: Right. My bad. So please Chanhyuk Park edit your post to type correctly $n^{(n^n)}$.

Comment: (And you also, please, @Mike)

Comment: Chanhyuk Park: at the beginning of your attempt, what you are expanding is not $n^{(n^n)}$ as it should, but the (too small) $(n^n)^n=n^{nn}=n^{n^2}$.

Comment: Why the hypothesis $n\ge3$? The strict inequality still holds for $n=2$. So, same as Will's very first comment: "what is the source of the problem"?

Comment: @AnneBauval is my $n^{n^n}$ formatting clear?

Comment: @Mike [In principle, yes it is!](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1633790) but I feel that parenthesis, though redundant, would be safer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT:** Take logarithms to conclude $$n^{n^n} \ge ((n!)!)^4,$$ and note that this gives you what you need.
En route, use the easy to see inequality $$M^M \ge 2^M (M!).$$

---

**IF YOU NEED MORE ELABORATION:**

First note that, taking logs of the LHS of the OP, we note: $$\log(n^{n^n}) = n^n \times \log (n).$$

On the other hand, taking logs of $(n!)!$ on the RHS of the OP:

$$\log((n!)!)$$ $$\le \log((n!)^{n!})$$
$$\le (n!)×\log(n!)$$ $$\le (n!)×\log(n^n)$$
$$\le (n!)\times (n \log n)$$ $$\le 2^{-n}n^n ×(n \log n),$$ Or in particular,

$$\log((n!)!) \le 2^{-n}n^n ×(n \log n). $$

However, for $n \ge 4$ note the inequality $$2^{-n} ×n  \le \frac{1}{4}.$$ So plugging this into the above gives

$$\log((n!)!) \le \frac{n^n \log n}{4}.$$

However, we have already observed
$$\log(n^{n^n}) = n^n\log(n),$$
and thus combining the above two relations yields
$$\log(n^{n^n}) \ge 4(\log((n!)!), $$ or equivalently,
$$n^{n^n} \ge (n!)!)^4.$$
Can you conclude yourself $$n × n! \le ((n!)!)^2$$ $$< ((n!)!)^3$$ yourself to get the desired result?